# Get Google Tags API event data via code (not via dashboard)

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, tracking

I am building an e-commerce website where we display hundreds of products on a main page. I need to show to vendors total view count (impressions) for each product.

I can store each impression by using Google Tags API. I call the below code when the product image comes into view.

```
window.gtag('event', 'offer_view', {
 'offer_id': offerID });
```

The events are registered at the Google analytics dashboard. However, I could not figure out a way retrieve event data using code. I need to display the impression count for each product to the vendors on my website. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is via google analytics data API. Unfortunately, there is no solution via gtag...